# Problem with Cycles Bake

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a really nice looking model made of multiple materials that I need to bake into one texture image.  I created a new image, placed an image texture node in each material, Smart UV Unwrapped the model onto the new texture, and cycles baked the textures (combined bake, direct and indirect).  However, the textures that baked looked nothing like the model. I had distorted textures, bizarre diagonals of wrong material arcing across the model, etc.  Any idea where I went wrong? Is it a problem with the model? How do I fix this?

EDIT: I think I figured it out- I believe the problem is I hadn't correctly joined different meshes by using the Boolean Union modifier.

Comment: maybe share your object if it's not a problem for you (or at least a part of it): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link- I just uploaded the .blend.  You'll see that I'm attempting to export this as three separate objects which are divided into different collections.  Each will have their own baked texture file, but I'm having trouble with all 3 parts. Of these, "B Concourse" is the most cleaned up.  The others have backwards-facing normals and extra crap I haven't dealt with yet. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: my best guess would be uv unwrapping issue